# How to run powershell code while in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to run:`

```
$filePath = "<input file path>"
    $wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible = $true
$txt = $wd.Documents.Open(
    $filePath,
    $false,
    $false,
    $false)
$wd.Documents[1].SaveAs("<export file path>")
$wd.Documents[1].Close()`
```

This is powershell code that needs to be run by a python script

Is there a way to store this as a string, completely in python, and then just run this block in powershell as if you had just copied and pasted it into powershell and pressed enter?
I am trying:

```
    import os
    script = """$filePath = "<input file path>"
        $wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $wd.Visible = $true
    $txt = $wd.Documents.Open(
        $filePath,
        $false,
        $false,
        $false)
    $wd.Documents[1].SaveAs("<export file path>")
    $wd.Documents[1].Close()"""
    os.system(script)`
```

I'm receiving:
'$filePath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: save it into a .ps1 and run it then

Comment: Save as a PS1 and then use `subprocess`. The only code I see do it this way is malware

Comment: If I save it as a PS1 how could I pass it arguments from python (the filenames)? Would I have to define a function with that inside?

Comment: You might consider doing this only using Python - driving Word using COM is essentially the same from Python as it is from Powershell.